# Casting at runtime using a System.Type object

Tags: vb.net, casting, type-conversion, runtime

I'm trying to create a function that takes a DataRow and populates an Object with the data.

This is my code:

```
    Public Shared Sub PopulateObjectFromDatarow(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal drwRow As DataRow)
        Dim lstFields = obj.GetType() _
         .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public) _
         .ToList()
        For Each field As FieldInfo In lstFields
            If drwRow.Table.Columns.Contains(field.Name) Then
                field.SetValue(obj, drwRow.Field(Of Object)(field.Name))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

It's basically matching up the column names to property names, and setting the object's property values.  This works great until I hit an Enum type!

I store an integer in the database for enum values, and I need to be able to convert it back to the enum value.

It might be worth me mentioning that I'm using .Net3.5 too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

p.s.  I've tried this already:

```
field.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(drwRow.Item(field.Name), field.FieldType))
```

To no avail...

Comment: You have to test specifically for Enums; They reflect as System,RuntimeType, use `GetType.BaseType.UnderlyingSystemType` will be `System.Enum`.  But I have to say, you could avoid all that by using a typed object; you could store a code to know which Type was read if the data could be from more than one Type.

Comment: The problem I have with that is that I'd have to hard-code in a switch statement for all the possible enum types, that's what I want to avoid.  I'm after a function that I can use even in other projects.  Good tip on how to test is it's an enum though, I'll see what I can do using that

Comment: To convert the integer back to the enum, use '[Enum].Parse(EnumType, IntegerAsString)`.

Comment: Thanks TnTinMn, I'll give it a go on Monday!  I seem to remember using something like that before, should have realised!

Comment: Both of the comments you two gave proved very useful!  I used a combination of both to come up with the solution I needed.  Accredited in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comments from TnTinMin and Plutonix, here's the solution!

```
    Public Shared Sub PopulateObjectFromDatarow(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal drwRow As DataRow)
        Dim lstFields = obj.GetType() _
         .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public) _
         .ToList()
        For Each field As FieldInfo In lstFields
            If drwRow.Table.Columns.Contains(field.Name) Then
                If field.FieldType Is GetType(String) Then
                    field.SetValue(obj, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(drwRow.Field(Of String)(field.Name)))
                ElseIf field.FieldType.IsGenericType Then
                    If drwRow.Field(Of Object)(field.Name) Is Nothing Then
                        field.SetValue(obj, Nothing)
                    Else
                        If field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()(0).IsEnum Then
                            field.SetValue(obj, [Enum].Parse(field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()(0), drwRow.Field(Of Integer)(field.Name).ToString()))
                        Else
                            field.SetValue(obj, drwRow.Field(Of Object)(field.Name))
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    If field.FieldType.IsEnum Then
                        field.SetValue(obj, [Enum].Parse(field.FieldType, drwRow.Field(Of Integer)(field.Name).ToString()))
                    Else
                        field.SetValue(obj, drwRow.Field(Of Object)(field.Name))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

This allows for the fact the field may be a nullable too!